# Rails 4.2 Using Heart Seed to import data on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku

I am using heartseed gem to import data in my rails application. It is working fine in my local machine.

When I try to do the same on heroku I get the following error.

```
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
require TABLES or CATALOGS if production
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/heart_seed-0.1.0/lib/heart_seed/db_seed.rb:73:in `import_all'
/app/db/seeds.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:180:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

On another note - I have tried http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel Roo for file upload and add data to database and it does not seem to work for me for rails 4.2 - can anyone guide me there as well pls?

Answer (score 1):

It's always worth checking out the source code, this is the line that is throwing the error:

https://github.com/sue445/heart_seed/blob/master/lib/heart_seed/db_seed.rb#L73

It looks like you need to set the `TABLES` and `CATALOGS` environment variables to make this work in production (so on Heroku). You can set environment variables for your Heroku application with `heroku config:set TABLES=...` etc.

The Railscast you linked to is pretty old so there is a fair chance that things will have moved on a bit since then. The Roo gem seems to be actively maintained so you will probably find up-to-date info in the README at https://github.com/roo-rb/roo .

Generally whenever I have had to import data from a spreadsheet I've saved the file as CSV and then written a simple Ruby script or Rake file that just uses the CSV library (http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/CSV.html) to do the import.